# Trying to get property of non-object in kartik expandrow in yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to use kartik expandrow.
In the first level query in PartiesSearch Model is-

```
$query = (new Query())->select(['district'])->from('districts');
```

In the second level query in ExpartiesSearch Model is -

```
$query = (new Query())->select(['parties_district','parties_partyname'])->from('parties');
```

The code for expandrow in index.php is -

```
[
            //['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
            'value' => function($model, $key, $index, $column){
                return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
            },
            'detail' => function($model, $key, $index, $column){
                $searchModel = new ExpartiesSearch();
                $searchModel-> parties_district = $model-> district;
                $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

                return Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_exparties', [
                    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    ]);                   

                },
            ],
```

I'm getting error -

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

The highlighted error line is -

```
$searchModel-> parties_district = $model-> district;
```

The same piece of code works fine if I change the query in PartiesSearch Model to

```
$sql = 'select district from districts';
$query = Districts::findBySql($sql);
```

But, I have to write the query in that particular format (Derived from Query Builder) only. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my test this:

```
$query = (new Query())->select(['district'])->from('districts');
```

will return you array of arrays. You need to use $model['district'] in this case.

```
[
//['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
'class' => 'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
    return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
},
'detail' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
    $searchModel = new ExpartiesSearch();
    $searchModel->parties_district = $model['district'];
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_exparties', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);

},
```

Try to use xdebug to see what exactly in your $model

Comment: You mean - $query = (new Query())->select($model['district'])->from('districts'); ?

Comment: i have updated answer. I mean this line: $searchModel->parties_district = $model['district'];